# how to call MongoTemplate function on Autowired instance of MongoTemplate in Spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, autowired, mongotemplate

I have configured the MongoDB connection in spring boot. Now I want to run a custom query by using MongoTemplate find() method. but spring boot is not allowing me to do so.

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public List<UserVO> findByQuery(String query) {
    List<UserVO> users = mongoTemplate.find(query, UserVO.class);
    return users;
}
```

mongoTemplate is autoconfigured with mongo URI, collection name is defined in UserVO.class using @Document.

Error: The method find(Query, Class) in the type MongoOperations is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class)

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As the error message clearly says, mongoTemplate.find(...) takes a `Query` object and class. You are passing a String and class. You have to convert your query which is in String to class `Query`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Working on creating the Query object. Stuck on adding multiple AND in a single OR statement using criteria.

Comment: put the code what you have tried , and what you want to achieve with the query

Comment: Its Completed now.

Answer (score 1):

As per specification mongoTemplate.find(Query query, Class entityClass) has such parameters

You need to specify Query like

```
new Query(Criteria.where("fieldName").is("searchValue")
```